# How Correlated sub query works

Tags: oracle11g

Would anyone please explain how the below query works, this query is to find the Nth highest salary.
 Will this works like bubble sort, just like taking one column of outer tab at a time and compare  with inner table..?  requesting you to explain with example.

```
Select distinct(salary) 
from emp e 
where &n = (
    Select count(distinct(salary)) 
    from emp 
    where e.salary<= salary);
```

Comment: Are you asking "conceptually, how does this work"?  Or are you asking "how does the database actually evaluate this"?  If you are asking the latter, the answer is "it depends".  We'd need to see the query plan that your version of Oracle chose given your particular data distribution to tell you.  And that could change moment to moment.

Comment: Ya, wanted to evaluate it.. just by iterations.. in particular I could not understand the sub query. if emp table as 5000,3000,6000,2000 respectively and we want need 2nd largest. will that first take 5000(e.salary) and compare with salary(5000,3000,6000,2000) and repeats for 3000,6000,2000..?

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are asking.  Are you trying to understand logically how this query gives you the results that it does (it's a very inefficient and rather clunky way to get the answer but it does work)?  Or do you understand what the query is doing and you want to know how the database chooses to implement the actual execution of the query?  For the latter, you'd need to provide the extra information I asked for initially.

Comment: Yes, trying to understand logically how this query gives  the results.

Comment: The same example is explained in detail here http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/database-sql/find-nth-highest-salary-sql/

Answer (score 0):

Let's take this example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b863c9/9

**Table**

```
create table salary (salary int);
insert into salary values (100);
insert into salary values (200);
insert into salary values (300);
insert into salary values (400);
insert into salary values (400);
insert into salary values (500);
insert into salary values (600);
insert into salary values (700);
insert into salary values (800);
insert into salary values (900);
```

**2nd highest**

```
Select distinct(salary) 
from salary e 
where 2 = (
    Select count(distinct(salary)) 
    from salary 
    where e.salary <= salary);
```

What is the sub query doing?

For each distinct salary in the outer query, the sub query will execute. `select distinct(salary) from salary` will list out all the distinct salary in no order.

For each of those salaries, the sub query will filter data higher than salary of the outer query's salary. Then it will count distinct salaries. Let's do a run through:

When outer query has salary of 100, sub query execute something like this: `select count(distinct(salary)) from salary where salary >= 100` resulting in 9. That means, there are 9 distinct salaries >= 100.

When outer query has salary of 200, sub query executes `select count(distinct(salary)) from salary where salary >= 200`. The result is 8.

As the query goes over and over again to the next salaries, it will come to a salary of 800. Sub query `select count(distinct(salary)) from salary where salary >= 800` results in 2. At this point, the `where` clause is satisfied for the outer query and the salary is printed.

As far as the algorithm, it depends on whether there's index or not and whether you use order or not.

Comment: If you find this answer useful, please or closure to your question by marking it accepted. Thank you.